# Bootstrap navbar menu not displayed on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 to make a simple theme.
My problem is, that when I view the page on mobile, and click the menu button, the menu shows up for 1 second, and then hide it self. If I click the button gain, it wont show up.

[Demo site here](https://kozetgyapot-arak.hu/adatkezelesi-tajekoztato)

My menu source code from the browser (I don't use the sticky classes)

```html
<header class="header header-sticky- header-transparent__">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
          <!-- Logo START -->
          <a class="navbar-brand" title="IQ Logistics Kft." href="https://kozetgyapot-arak.hu">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://themes.potenzaglobalsolutions.com/html/bulky/images/logo.svg" alt="IQ Logistics Kft.">
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto_">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" title="Kezdőlap" href="https://kozetgyapot-arak.hu/">Kezdőlap</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" title="Rólunk" href="https://kozetgyapot-arak.hu/rolunk">Rólunk</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" title="Szolgáltatások" href="https://kozetgyapot-arak.hu/szolgaltatasok">Szolgáltatások</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" title="Elérhetőségeink" href="https://kozetgyapot-arak.hu/elerhetosegeink">Elérhetőségeink</a></li>            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="mr-5 mr-lg-0 d-sm-flex d-none align-items-center">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://kozetgyapot-arak.hu/arajanlat-kerese">Árajánlat kérése <i class="fa fa-chevron-right ml-1"></i></a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Thank you, if someone can help me.

Comment: _“I am using bootstrap 4”_ - you’re only doing that partially … Your `bootstrap.min.css` you embedded, is in version `4.4.1`, but `bootstrap.min.js` is embedded in `3.3.5`. You can not mix between different major versions of BS like that, you need to embed the _script_ for the 4.x version as well, and not that for `3.x`.

Comment: BS 3 used the classes `.collapse.in` to make the collapsed element visible, and that is what the JS is currently trying to do in your site - but there is no matching CSS, to make the element visible based on that. BS 4 uses `.collapse.show` instead, and _that_ class does not get set by your JS (because it was embedded in the wrong version.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine with this html. Note that I did leave out the Font Awesome stylesheet in the snippet below. Also note that the popper script is bundled in the bootstrap script so you heave to remove it from your project as an extra script.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<header class="header header-sticky- header-transparent__">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" title="IQ Logistics Kft." href="https://kozetgyapot-arak.hu">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://themes.potenzaglobalsolutions.com/html/bulky/images/logo.svg" alt="IQ Logistics Kft.">
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" title="Kezdőlap" href="https://kozetgyapot-arak.hu/">Kezdőlap</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" title="Rólunk" href="https://kozetgyapot-arak.hu/rolunk">Rólunk</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" title="Szolgáltatások" href="https://kozetgyapot-arak.hu/szolgaltatasok">Szolgáltatások</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" title="Elérhetőségeink" href="https://kozetgyapot-arak.hu/elerhetosegeink">Elérhetőségeink</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="mr-5 mr-lg-0 d-sm-flex d-none align-items-center">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://kozetgyapot-arak.hu/arajanlat-kerese">Árajánlat kérése <i class="fa fa-chevron-right ml-1"></i></a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```